# Can not get the text from span tag when scrape web using selenium

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I'm trying the scrape linkedin job using selenium but i cannot get the text from the tag. Here is my code:

```
company_details = wd.find_element(By.XPATH,"//div[@class='mt5mb2']/li[1]").find_elements(By.TAG_NAME,"span").text
                if " · " in company_details:
                    company_size = company_details.split(" · ")[0]
                    company_industry = company_details.split(" · ")[1]
```

It just return none in company_details
but the other like this still works and return the job title:

```
job_title = wd.find_element(By.XPATH,"//h2[@class='t-24 t-bold jobs-unified-top-card__job-title']") 
job_title = job_title.text
```

i have tried the other ways like find by tag name but still not work

Comment: Try with the getAttribute method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the answer:

It seems like you are trying to extract text from a span tag using Selenium, but you're encountering issues. Instead of using `.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME,"span").text`, use `.find_element(By.TAG_NAME,"span").text` to get the text content from the span tag. The difference is that `.find_element()` returns a single element, while `.find_elements()` returns a list of elements. Additionally, you should make sure that the element you're trying to access is properly loaded before attempting to extract its text.

Here's the corrected code snippet:

```py
# Find the element containing company details
company_details_element = wd.find_element(By.XPATH, "//div[@class='mt5mb2']/li[1]/span")

# Get the text from the span tag
company_details = company_details_element.text

if " · " in company_details:
    company_size, company_industry = company_details.split(" · ")
```

This should help you retrieve the text from the span tag successfully.

Answer (score 0):

if you use the xpath, you should use the full absolutely xpath.

and find_elements return multi result and you should specify the index

like:

```
k = wd.find_elements( , )[0]
k.text
```